# Capistrano Rails deployment -- "could not find gem...rolling back"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, bundler

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app from OS X development workstation to RedHat Linux 5 production server.

I put the full output of `cap deploy` into **[this gist](https://gist.github.com/2482390)**.

This part of the output that shows the problem, I think:

```
 ** [out :: devuser@web3] Could not find gem 'awesome_print (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
 ** [out :: devuser@web3] Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
    command finished in 663ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

These are some of the issues I see here:

- `awesome_print` is in the `:development` group, so Capistrano shouldn't be trying to install it in production.
- In any case all of the gems are available in rubygems.org so there should be no problem installing them.

If anyone knows a way to get `cap deploy` to work I would be grateful to know it. Thanks.

---

My Gemfile...

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
gem 'capistrano', '2.11.2'
gem 'haml-rails', '0.3.4'
gem 'net-ldap', '0.3.1'
gem 'bourbon', '1.4.0'
gem 'simple_form', '2.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'

group :development, :test do
end

group :development do
  gem 'wirble'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem "autotest", '4.4.6'
  gem "autotest-rails-pure", '4.1.2'
  gem "autotest-fsevent", '0.2.8'
  gem "autotest-growl", '0.2.16'
end

group :test do
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', '0.9.10'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: The 'awesome_print' gem is listed under the development group but when you're deploying to prod bundler will ignore the dev group gems

Comment: Doh, I just reread your question and noticed you wrote that! :) Have you tried a deployment with that line taken out of the Gemfile? (not ideal, but just to see if it works)

Comment: Bundler resolves dependencies and versions with *everything*, across all groups. It may not install all of them, but it at least has to find the gemspecs. This keeps development == production, no matter what you install. Unfortunately, I can't help you solve the missing gem error.

Comment: @KreeK Yes. If I comment a gem out it just moves on to another one and fails to "find it in any of the sources".

Comment: Since you didn't mention it, have you tried installing the gem manually on the system? Just to make sure the problem isn't rubygems itself, or some network issue (I've had trouble installing before because the server had messed up DNS settings and couldn't find rubygems.org, but I could SSH in just fine, so it was a bit hard to find)

Comment: @PerfectlyNormal Bundler wants gems to be in `vendor`. But yes, I am able to install gems -- RubyGems is working correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your capistrano recipe actually did not run bundle install altogether. Make sure you have `require "bundler/capistrano"` in your deploy.rb recipe.